# Is there a solitaire version of Bang?

Tags: house-rules, bang

I love playing Bang! but I'm finding it hard to play a game with my friends, because of our busy schedules.

I would love to play a solitaire version of Bang! if it existed, so that I could get my spaghetti-western card game fix between groups.

Does anyone know of, or has anyone created solitaire rules for this game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Unofficial Bang! Blog](http://bangcardgame.blogspot.com/) has, among other great variations, a [set of instructions](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8wPX7XHoGh_ZGMxYTMzOTUtYWUxMi00YjYwLWE2ZmQtMTk4NmU3N2E5YjY5/edit?hl=en_US&pli=1) (pdf) for single player Bang!

The main changes in this solitaire version are that all roles and cards held are known to the player from the beginning, and that you play as both the sheriff and the deputy, with other "NPCs" making semi-predetermined moves.

You can increase the difficulty by giving more cards to NPCs at the start, but not too many! The author can barely survive with two cards given to each NPC at start. (I'm afraid even I'm not *that* good :p)

Not always having a large crowd to Bang with, I have thoroughly enjoyed this rule set and have now almost played it more than "normal" Bang!

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but it may solve your problem and it's sure good info for those who want to play "alone":

There's an [official app for iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bang!-the-official-video-game/id406634232?mt=8) devices that let you play offline against NPCs or online with other people.

As I write this, the app costs US$4.99, but there are two special edition versions that are **free**, the [BANG! Italia 150](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bang!-italia-150/id425995340?mt=8) and the [BANG! 4th of July](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bang!-4th-of-july/id444997715?mt=8).